# I am trying to get java to find out all the multiples of a user inputted variable integer

Tags: java, variables, numbers, integer

I am trying to make a vacuum cleaner with a user input for size and speed that should go up to the edge and then go down and turn around and when it reaches the other side turn around again and keep constantly going from one side to another. I know how to make it go down no matter the size but I want to make the distance it goes down equal so I need to find these multiples so when the vacuum cleaner reaches them it should stop going down and rather go right or left.

I am trying to get java to find all the multiples of a user inputted variable. It is supposed to be an integer and a class variable. I have searched this website and Google for quite a long time now but I am confused how to make java find all this out and how to use it. Please help. Thank you.

Here is the code I use to make it go down(and all movements):

posX - Current x position

posY - Current y position

speed - User inputted variable for speed in pixels rectangle travels at

speedY - Equal to speed but used for y movements only

x - User inputted width of rectangle

y - User inputted height of rectangle

halfY - Half of y and distance rectangle should travel down every time

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    if(posY == 0){
        posX = posX + speed;
    }
    if((posX <= 0)&&(posY != 0)){
        posX = 0;//posX + speed - speed;
        posY = posY + speedY;
    }
    if(posX >= 600 - x){
        posX = posX + speed - speed;
        posY = posY + speedY;       
    }
    if(posY >= y - halfY){
        posX = posX - speed;
    }
    repaint();
}
```

My main function code

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println("Place in the width of your vaccum cleaner here:");
    Scanner myX = new Scanner(System.in);
    x = myX.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Place in the height of your vaccum cleaner here:");     
    Scanner myY = new Scanner(System.in);
    y = myY.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Place the speed in pixels that the vaccum cleaner should travel at:");
    Scanner mySpeed = new Scanner(System.in);
    speed = mySpeed.nextInt();  

    JFrame jf = new JFrame("Title");
    jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    Vaccum v = new Vaccum();
    jf.add(v);
    jf.setSize(600, 400);
    jf.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. It would help if you showed something you tried.   You might want to read an introductory text on Java that discusses what a variable is, and what a loop is, and you might figure this out on your own. It turns out that figuring this kind of thing out on your own is better when you're learning. Good luck.

Comment: I googled for an answer to your question but couldn't find one. Perhaps you could  provide the first one?

Comment: Ok I will try again.

Comment: Which one are you talking about?

Comment: @user62: It's highly unlikely that you'll find an exact solution for what you're trying to do that you can just copy.  Instead, start with some introductory tutorials on Java and begin to practice making simple "Hello World" programs to get a feel for how the language works.  As you learn the basics (variables, methods, classes, conditions, loops, performing calculations, etc.) you can start to define and build the specific functionality you want.

Comment: @David I have already done that

Comment: @user62: Ok, that's a good start.  Now where are you stuck?  What error or unexpected behavior are you seeing in your code?

Comment: Ah I have figured it out, but turns out another problem has come up...

Comment: A problem I am facing with getters.

Comment: I have already asked the question.

Comment: But no answers yet.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have figured it out.
Here is what to do:

currentYPos - Current position on y axis

```
if(currentYPos % y == 0){...}
```